# Adding completion handler before Segue

Tags: ios, swift

How could I add a completion handler to this code so that I am sure that the view does not call that Segue at the end before I get "city" or an error?

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let longitude = locManager.location?.coordinate.longitude
    let latitude = locManager.location?.coordinate.latitude
    print(latitude)
    let location = CLLocation(latitude: latitude!, longitude: longitude!)
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setDouble(longitude!, forKey: "longitude")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setDouble(latitude!, forKey: "latitude")

    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            let pa = placemarks! as [CLPlacemark]

            var placeMark: CLPlacemark!
            placeMark = pa[0]

            if let city = placeMark.addressDictionary!["City"] as? String {
                print(city)
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(city, forKey: "city")
            }
        } 
        else {
            print("Error: " + error!.localizedDescription)
        }
    })

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toMain", sender: self)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the call in your first `if` statement, when you don't get any error.

```
if( error == nil)
{
    // make sure value you're getting is correct and save to NSUserDefaults
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toMain", sender: self)
}
else
{
    // handle the error
}
```

Comment: genious! it worked.. As a learning exercise, could you kindly explain what is going on there, and why that made the Segue wait?

Comment: By putting the `performSegueWithIdentifier` in `if`, you are making it wait for the result from `reverseGeocodeLocation`.

Comment: Exactly. The original code calls the asynchronous API and then performs the segue right away, without waiting for it to complete. In the answer code, the segue is performed from within the `completion handler`, i.e. it is run only _after_ the query completes (and furthermore, only if it _also_ succeeds).